# \ifpdf vs \sys_if_output_pdf:TF

Tags: xetex, latex3

I've got a document that I want to be engine-agnostic (to be used by lecturers in mathematics department). I'd been using `\ifpdf` (from `iftex`) and separately `\ifPDFTeX` and `\IfXeTeX` &c. The point is to detect "output to PDF in any engine" separately from "using engine pdfTeX".

I switched to `\sys_if_output_pdf:TF`, which I expected to be functionally identical to `\ifpdf`.

I find that my check for "output to PDF in any engine" is failing always in XeTeX, but succeeds in pdfTeX and LuaTeX...why?

I'm compiling with `latexmk -xelatex -latexoption='-8bit --synctex=1 -file-line-error' -r MAT-25.tex`

---

Please let me know what I need to upload to answer the question; the log does not seem to have any information, but maybe something else does? I don't know where to look.

Comment: XeTeX is more or less always in dvi mode. It first outputs `.xdv` file, then automatically calls `xdvipdfmx` to output pdf. The CLI option `-no-pdf` will make xetex stops at `.xdv` and currently there's no way to detect if `-no-pdf` is used or not within xetex.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ ok, that makes sense...but isn't XeTeX alsö "always" in PDF mode? It can output PDF metadata that would error if pdfTeX was run in DVI mode...right?

Comment: No. `xelatex -no-pdf main.tex` will output `.xdv` only, not pdf. With latexmk, by default it always calls xelatex with `-no-pdf`. You finally get pdf doesn't mean there's no intermediate output. Also I think dvi/pdf mode is a concept only available to engines that can output pdf directly. And unfortunately, xetex is not such one.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Looks like an answer to me